# How to install RoBMA in r

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install `RoBMA` package in r but it constantly returning an error or it says

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/vw/l7bfwbt17_b5xwkl593ckppr0000gp/T//RtmpfuP3x6/downloaded_packages
```

I tried use this using the following code:

```
install.packages("RoBMA", repos = "/var/folders/vw/l7bfwbt17_b5xwkl593ckppr0000gp/T//RtmpfuP3x6/downloaded_packages")
```

but it still doesn't work. I tried this as well

```
devtools::install_github("fbartos/RoBMA")
```

But still doesn't work. Does anyone know how to install this package. I updated my r and rstudio but not sure what is the issue

Comment: *"constantly returning an error"* ... what error? Showing us the code you used is a good start, but there are so many possible failure points for installing a package that I'm not going to try to guess what you could be seeing.

Comment: When I just try to install using `install.packages("RoBMA")`, it returns me this `The downloaded binary packages are in /var/folders/vw/l7bfwbt17_b5xwkl593ckppr0000gp/T//RtmpfuP3x6/downloaded_packages`. Then I tried this `install.packages("RoBMA", repos = "file:///var/folders/vw/l7bfwbt17_b5xwkl593ckppr0000gp/T//RtmpfuP3x6/downloaded_packages/")` but it gives me the following error `Warning in install.packages : cannot open compressed file '/var/folders/vw/l7bfwbt17_b5xwkl593ckppr0000gp/T//RtmpfuP3x6/downloaded_packages/src/contrib/PACKAGES', probable reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: The following error message is also one them ```library("RoBMA")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RoBMA’ in get(method, envir = envir):
 lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RoBMA/R/RoBMA.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(method, envir = envir) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1 ```

Comment: Okay, getting somewhere. First, the *warning* (not error) is fairly important to your question, you need to [edit] it and add it there. (Why? Comments are easily skipped by other readers or intentionally hidden by the Stack interface.) The second (PACKAGES) is because you cannot do `repos="file:///..."`, that is not a package repository directory, so installing from it as such is incorrect. Third, I've never seen "downloaded binary packages are in ..." unless there was a message/warning/error causing installation to fail. Are you certain there was nothing more?

Comment: The "lazy-load" error is because R doesn't deal well when help docs within a package change after having been loaded. The fix is to restart R and reinstall the package. This likely puts us back at square one of how to install this one package, but I still see no indication of why it thought to tell you where the downloaded packages are saved. Does this one package have dependencies that have any other warnings/errors during _their_ installation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I sorted out the problem by restarting the r. The package is working now. Thank you